# Is there a way I can remove the need for an "as <classname>. In a property changed event method?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
    private static void IsAvailablePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if((bindable as ArrowGridTemplate).FR != null)
        {
            if ((bool)newValue)
            {
                (bindable as ArrowGridTemplate).Opacity = 1;
                (bindable as ArrowGridTemplate).IsEnabled = true;
                
            }
            else
            {
                (bindable as ArrowGridTemplate).Opacity = 0.5;
                (bindable as ArrowGridTemplate).IsEnabled = false;

            }
        }
    }
```

Is there some way I could change this so almost every line didn't require the:

```
(bindable as ArrowGridTemplate)
```

Comment: `if (bindable is ArrowGridTemplate temp && temp.FR != null) ... temp.Opacity = 1; ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`is` type pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression) here:

```
if(bindable is ArrowGridTemplate template && template.FR != null)
{
    if ((bool)newValue)
    {
        template.Opacity = 1;
        template.IsEnabled = true;
            
    }
    else
    {
        template.Opacity = 0.5;
        template.IsEnabled = false'
    }
}
```

`ArrowGridTemplate template` here is kind of a like a "variable declaration", so you can change `template` to be any name you want.

Comment: so "if (bindable is ArrowGridTemplate template" will also test it and make sure that it's an ArrowGridTemplate?  How about if it's null, should I also test to check if bindable isn't null ?

Comment: It will make sure that it's an `ArrowGridTemplate`. Read the link I provided for more info. I don't think `bindable` can be null, so you don't need to check it. You would need to check for nulls if you were using `as`, because the conversion would fail. @RichardS